# ¿como imprimir un "print" solamente una vez dentro de un while de Python?

Tags: python, whatsapp, pywhatkit

Hola compañeros tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
    i = 0
while i == 0:
    tiempo = datetime.datetime.now()
    Hora = int(tiempo.hour)
    Minuto = int(tiempo.minute)+1
    if Hora >6 and Hora <9:
        print("Esperando minuto de envio...")
    else:
        print ("Esperando la hora de envío...")
        i=0
```

Lo que quiero es que siempre que imprima alguno de los dos prints por consola se muestren solo una vez y no infinitamente hasta que se cumpla la condición, agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Puedes poner una marca antes del `while`: `marca = 0` y la comparas con `0` antes del `if`. Una vez dentro del `if` la pones a `1` y ya no entra más. Puedes crear otra diferente para el `else` si quieres...

Comment: Además, añade un `time.sleep()` dentro del while o te estará consumiendo CPU constantemente para nada. Puedes pasarle al sleep() un tiempo de 60 para que se ejecute el bucle sólamente una vez por minuto, o si quieres grano más fino, pasale un tiempo menor (1 segundo por ejemplo?)

Comment: Mejor aún... partir de `datetime.now()` sabes qué hora es. Calcula cuántos segundos faltan para que termine la espera y haz un `time.sleep()` de ese tiempo, evitando por completo el bucle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El patrón usual es tener una variable booleana que marque la condición. Esta variable controla la ejecución de la opción, y cambia tan pronto se ejecuta:

```
primera_vez = True
while True:
...
    if hay_que_imprimir:
        if primera_vez:
            imprimir()
            primera_vez = False
...
```

Aplicado a tu caso, la solución es:

```
i = 0
espera_hora = True
espera_minuto = True
while i == 0:
    tiempo = datetime.datetime.now()
    Hora = int(tiempo.hour)
    Minuto = int(tiempo.minute)+1
    if Hora >6 and Hora <9:
        if espera_hora:
            print("Esperando minuto de envio...")
            espera_hora = False
    else:
        if espera_minuto:
            print ("Esperando la hora de envío...")
            espera_minuto = False
        i=0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias bro, funcionó perfectamente!